# Using interface name as Variable type

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.8.x

In solidity, see below code ..... How is that the interface name is being used as variable type ?
See the comments in below code

```
pragma solidity 0.8.11;

import "../interfaces/ISpool.sol";
// ... other imports

abstract contract VaultBase is IVaultBase, VaultImmutable, SpoolOwnable, SpoolPausable, BaseConstants {
    using Bitwise for uint256;
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    /* ========== STATE VARIABLES ========== */

    /// @notice The central Spool contract
    ISpool internal immutable spool;   // ISpool is interface name and it is
                                       // being used as variable type. What this means ?

}
```

ISpool interface:

```
interface ISpool is ISpoolExternal, ISpoolReallocation, ISpoolDoHardWork, ISpoolStrategy, ISpoolBase {}
```

How is that the interface name is being used as variable type ?

Comment: When used as variable an interface is an address that can be used to call the interface functions.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look in this code example:

```
interface B{
    function func() external;
}

contract A {
    B b;
    constructor(address contract_implements_b) public {
        b = B(contract_implements_b);
    }
}
```

Here there is `interface B` and there is `contract A`.

`contract A` receives an address as a parameter, this address points to another contract that implements `interface B`. After we initialized b we can call `b.func()` in our `contract A` without knowing the full ABI of the address's contract we got.

Comment: In the code where have you called `b.func()` ?

Comment: I didn’t, just mentioned it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

you are initializing a variable here:

```
ISpool internal immutable spool;
```

You are describing that `spool` object is visible internally and it is read-only. Also, it will have methods that are specified in `ISpool` interface.